# Rails gem tweetstream with Encryption not available on this event-machine error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, eventmachine, tweetstream

I'm trying to display tweets using `gem tweetstream` and following the guide at https://github.com/tweetstream/tweetstream

In my `tweets_helper.rb`

```
  require "twitter" require 'tweetstream'

  module TweetsHelper   
    @@client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = Rails.application.config.twitter_key
    config.consumer_secret     = Rails.application.config.twitter_secret
    config.access_token        = Rails.application.config.twitter_oauth_token
    config.access_token_secret = Rails.application.config.twitter_oauth_secret
   end

  def user_timeline
    @@client.user_timeline   
  end

  TweetStream.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = Rails.application.config.twitter_key
    config.consumer_secret     = Rails.application.config.twitter_secret
    config.oauth_token        = Rails.application.config.twitter_oauth_token
    config.oauth_token_secret = Rails.application.config.twitter_oauth_secret
    config.auth_method= :oauth  

  end

    TweetStream::Client.new.track('Pink Floyd') do |status|
      puts "#{status.text}"     
    end 
 end
```

But this throws me this error in the terminal and shuts down the localserver

> c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/tweetstream-2.6.1/lib/tweet
>   stream/client.rb:400: warning: epoll is not supported on this platform
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/tweetstream-2.6.1/lib/tweet
>   stream/client.rb:401: warning: kqueue is not supported on this
>   platform terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'std::runtime_error'   what():  Encryption not available on this
>   event-machine
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

However the server runs if I remove

```
TweetStream::Client.new.track('Pink Floyd') do |status|  
  puts "#{status.text}"
end
```

How do I fix this error?

UPDATE
I think all signs point to installing libssl-dev https://github.com/plamoni/SiriProxy/issues/41. On Ubuntu it is `aptitude install libssl-dev`.
How do I do it on windows 8?