# Install libssl-dev for Rails on Window 8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, tweetstream, libssl

I'm having this error when running `gem tweetstream`

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
>   what(): Encryption not available on this event-machine

I understand it has something to do with my libssl. How do I install libssl-dev on windows?

Is there an equivalent of ubuntu's `aptitude install libssl-dev` for windows or a gem?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842637/rails-gem-tweetstream-with-encryption-not-available-on-this-event-machine-error